# how do I redirect from one controller to another controller which is in another folder in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to navigate from(AddToCartController) one controller to another(Singlestepcheckoutcontroller) which is in different folder.

[image]
My code to redirect is as follows:

```
return "redirect:" + "/checkout/single";
```

In web browser console I get **Status=(Cancelled) and Type=pending**

I have the mapping in my other controller as follows:

```
 @Controller
    @Scope("tenant")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/checkout/single")
    public class SingleStepCheckoutController extends AbstractCheckoutController
    {
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try `"redirect:" + "checkout/single"` ? (Note that, i have omitted the slash before `checkout`

Comment: Tried no luck.got an error in browser console as 404.

Comment: You're code to redirect seems fine. What happens when you call the destination URL directly from the browser? ``redirect:`` also only works in case your ViewResolver supports this.

Comment: @Joroen : From browser it works and redirect works in other controllers.

Comment: @day_dreamer this is from my application, controllers in different packages

`return "redirect:/app/grid/loadColumnConfig";`

where `grid` is my `@RequestMapping(value = "grid")` at controller level, and `loadColumnConfig` is at method level. `app` is in my `web.xml`, `<url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>`